# block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor - Webflux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm writing a custom exchangeFilterResponseProcessor, what I need to do inside this method is number 1 check if we are getting "401 - unauthorized" and number 2 check the body of the response, if the body of the response has errorCode "5003" then throw an Exception,

any idea?

Current code is throwing me this error:

"block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4"

```
    private Mono<ClientResponse> exchangeFilterResponseProcessor(ClientResponse response) {
        Man respuesta = response.bodyToMono(Man.class).block;
        HttpStatus status = response.statusCode();
        if (HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.equals(status)) {
            Object res = response.bodyToMono(Man.class).subscribe(m -> {
                if (m.getErrorCode() == "5003") {
                    Mono.error(new Exception("CustomException!!!!!"));
                }
            });

        }
        return Mono.just(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the response body in a reactive flow - as you discovered, blocking a publisher is inappropriate in the reactive stack.

As a sidenote, it's also important to mention that strings should never be compared with `==`, only with `equals()`, but this is unrelated, so I won't get into it here.

A possible solution:

```java
private Mono<ClientResponse> exchangeFilterResponseProcessor(ClientResponse res) {
    return res.bodyToMono(Man.class)
        .filter(m -> !(res.statusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED && m.getErrorCode().equals("5003")))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("CustomException")))
        .thenReturn(res);
}
```

**EDIT**: Corrected predicate

Comment: Why if the .filter() returns true the . switchIfEmpty is being executed? @cpigeon

Comment: @Andres Apologies, the predicate was wrong. Updated my answer.